# How to debug issues with INSERT INTO syntax?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, sql-insert

I am a beginner programer at senior year in high school, and I need help with my INSERT INTO syntax. For some reason I receive an error from this line:

```
string SqlStr = string.Format("INSTERT INTO Customers(Username, Password, Email, BirthDate, Gender, ID, DLName, DLSurname, DLNumber, DLExp, Type)VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}')", s.username, s.password, s.email, s, s.birthdate, s.gender, s.id, s.dlname, s.dlsurname, s.dlnumber, s.dlexp, "normal");
base.insertRow(SqlStr);
```

now most of my experience is with C# so SQL is brand new to me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please add the error you are getting to help others find the problem in your query.

Comment: There's a typo, but more importantly your code is vulnerable to *SQL Injection Attacks*. You should use parameterized SQL to address that - but it's hard to help you do that without knowing more about what framework you're using. (As an aside, `insertRow` would be conventionally named `InsertRow`. Now's a great time to start learning about .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: (Additionally, but separately, it would be good to learn a bit more about security in terms of avoiding putting plaintext passwords in databases. Maybe you're already using a hash of some description though - it's not entirely clear.)

Answer (score 1):

`INSTERT` is a typo, it needs to be `INSERT`.

That said, please take a look at bind parameters instead of string concatenation.

For example, just print the string you would send to the database if my username is

`x', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null); DROP DATABASE; --`

Mandatory link to [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).